# gnuplot value on Y-axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file which contains two column data. when plotted, it looks like [image: gnuplot image]

Green line is showing mean.
I want to show mean value on Y-axis. Is it possible?
code:

`set style data lines`
`set termoption enhanced`
`set term png`
`set title "17th oct"`
`stats 'data/17-10-2013' using 1:2 nooutput`
`set xdata time`
`set timefmt "%s"`
`set format x "%H"`
`set output "images/17_DB.png"`
`plot "data/17-10-2013" using 1:3 title " Data" , STATS_mean_y title " Mean"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three different options to display the value:

```
set term pngcairo enhanced
set output "images/17_DB.png"

set title "17th oct"
stats 'data/17-10-2013' using 1:2 nooutput
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%H"

# first option    
set ytics add (sprintf('%.1f', STATS_mean_y) STATS_mean_y)

# second option
set ytics add ('' STATS_mean_y)
set rmargin 3
set label left at graph 1.05,first STATS_mean_y sprintf('%.1f', STATS_mean_y)

set style data lines

# third option inside the key label
plot "data/17-10-2013" using 1:3 title "Data" , \
     STATS_mean_y title sprintf("Mean = %.1f", STATS_mean_y)
```

Here some notes about the different options:

1. The first option is the easiest, but the label could overlap with another label (here with the `0`).
2. The second option adds an empty mayor tic, and places the label on the right side. This requires the right margin to be increased manually (you may need to use another value, e.g. `set rmargin 2` and other coordinates).
3. The third option just places the value in the key (legend) entry.

For a nicer `x`-axis, you may want to add `set autoscale xfix`, which gets you rid of the empty space on the right side.

Comment: is it possible to show legends on axis, like time(s) on y-axis?

Comment: Use e.g. `set xlabel 'time (s)'`